# Array of polynomials

Tags: functions, warning-messages, polynomials

So I have a big list of 75 polynomials which I need to apply a sequence of operations to.

My original program (an extract of which is below) worked fine:

```
x[z_] := (1 - 4*z^2 + z^4)*(1 + 4*z^2 + z^4)
k[z_] := -108*z^4*(1 + z^4)^4 
qsquared[z_] := Simplify[x[z]^3 - k[z]];
qdegree = Exponent[qsquared[z], z];
qcoeff = Coefficient[qsquared[z], z, qdegree]; ...
```

However, I have 75 x and k.  What I wanted to do is start the program with them all just listed

```
Array[x, 76]
Array[k, 76]  

x[1][z_] := 4*(1 + 12*z + 4*z^3 + 11*z^4 - 6*z^5 + 7*z^6 - 2*z^7 + z^8)
k[1][z_] := -432*(31 + 14*z - 3*z^2 + 18*z^3 - 5*z^4 + 4*z^5)
x[2][z_] :=  (1 + z^2)*(1 + 27*z^2 + 27*z^4 + 9*z^6)
k[2][z_] := 64*z^2*(3 + 3*z^2 + z^4)
x[3][z_] := 4*(1 + 4*z - 16*z^2 + 12*z^3 + 27*z^4 - 18*z^5 - 9*z^6 +18*z^7 +9*z^8)
k[3][z_] := 16*(-1 + 4*z)^3*(21 - 6*z - 9*z^2 + 14*z^3 + 9*z^4)
```

And so on.  I then tried looping through with:

```
Do[
 qsquared[z_] := Simplify[x[i][z]^3 - k[i][z]];
 qdegree = Exponent[qsquared[z], z];
 qcoeff = Coefficient[qsquared[z], z, qdegree];
.....
, {i, 76}]
```

Which gets a Set::write error.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Array[x, 76]` and `Array[k, 76]` with `Clear`:

```
ClearAll[x, k];
x[1][z_] := 4*(1 + 12*z + 4*z^3 + 11*z^4 - 6*z^5 + 7*z^6 - 2*z^7 + z^8)
k[1][z_] := -432*(31 + 14*z - 3*z^2 + 18*z^3 - 5*z^4 + 4*z^5)
x[2][z_] :=  (1 + z^2)*(1 + 27*z^2 + 27*z^4 + 9*z^6)
k[2][z_] := 64*z^2*(3 + 3*z^2 + z^4)
x[3][z_] := 4*(1 + 4*z - 16*z^2 + 12*z^3 + 27*z^4 - 18*z^5 - 9*z^6 +18*z^7 +9*z^8)
k[3][z_] := 16*(-1 + 4*z)^3*(21 - 6*z - 9*z^2 + 14*z^3 + 9*z^4)
```

Your previous definitions of `x[z_]` and `k[z_]` as polynomials are cause problems with defining the subvalues `x[1][z_]` etc.: The head `x[1]` evaluates to the integer `-12`, so your code in effect tries to define `(-12)[z_]`, which is not allowed.

It might be better to put the polynomials in two lists (or a 2 by 75 or 76 array), and manipulate the lists than to define separate functions. It's hard to say without the seeing the full application. But you didn't ask about it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `Table` to list your results

```
Table[qsquared = Simplify[x[i][z]^3 - k[i][z]];qdegree = Exponent[qsquared, z];
{qsquared, qdegreeCoefficient[qsquared, z, qdegree]}, {i, 3}]
(*{{432 (31 + 14 z - 3 z^2 + 18 z^3 - 5 z^4 + 4 z^5) +64 (1 + 12 z + 4 z^3 + 11 z^4 - 6 z^5 + 7 z^6 - 2 z^7 + z^8)^3,1536}
, {(-1 + 54 z^2 + 297 z^4 + 504 z^6 + 405 z^8 + 162 z^10 + 27 z^12)^2,17496}
, {16 (-5 + 21 z - 63 z^2 + 270 z^4 - 216 z^5 - 252 z^6 + 
 432 z^7 + 162 z^8 - 270 z^9 + 162 z^11 + 54 z^12)^2, 1119744}}*)
```